# How to restrict user input on a text area to match a specific string in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to remember about 3 pages of text verbatim, including punctuation. I'm attempting to build a simple JavaFX program to quiz myself on this material.

I'd like to use a text area for the user to type input. The user is to type into the text area - if the input correctly matches the existing string (the stuff I need to remember), the text is allowed as input into the text field. If they make a mistake, the input simply isn't recognized and no incorrect input will appear in the text area.

What's the best approach for something like this? I'm pretty new to JavaFX and Java in general. I've got my UI set up in JavaFX, I'm just unsure how to implement the check on the text area. Thank you.

Comment: interesting approach .. though to me it looks like you want to put off the real effort (of memorizing) as long as possible by districting yourself with a completely unrelated problem (of coding) - bet you would alread have memorized the first page if you focused on that <g>

Comment: *districting == distracting ...

Comment: I find memorizing large text, music, etc. without cues quite difficult.  If I were to try do this, I'd try to build in cues, such as that suggested at http://www.productivity501.com/how-to-memorize-verbatim-text/294/, which takes the first letter of each word in the text, which you read, then try to recall the word for matching the letter.  A program to assist is that probably wouldn't be all that difficult to create.   Perhaps it would work well, perhaps it wouldn't (to test you could have a few people try to memorize text with and without the tool).

Comment: Another thing you could enforce in the tool, is only memorizing short sections at a time (e.g. < 10 words).  Short term memory is very limited, to efficiently memorize you need to get stuff transferred from short-term to long-term memory.  And if you just try to memorize a whole large passage all at once, it won't work well.  You also need rescue points, so if you are reciting and forget, you can pick-up at some near point that you remember, rather than rote starting from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) that only allows the new text if it resembles the expected text. Here's a *proof-of-concept*:

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextArea area = new TextArea();
    area.setPrefRowCount(5);
    area.setPrefColumnCount(25);
    area.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new ExpectedTextFilter("Hello, World!")));

    StackPane root = new StackPane(area);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private static class ExpectedTextFilter implements UnaryOperator<Change> {

    private final String expectedText;

    ExpectedTextFilter(String expectedText) {
      this.expectedText = Objects.requireNonNull(expectedText);
    }

    @Override
    public Change apply(Change change) {
      if (change.isContentChange()) {
        if (change.isReplaced()) {
          // simply don't allow replacements
          return null;
        } else if (change.isDeleted()) {
          // only allow deletions from the end of the control's text
          return change.getRangeEnd() == change.getControlText().length() ? change : null;
        } else {
          return expectedText.startsWith(change.getText(), change.getRangeStart()) ? change : null;
        }
      }
      return change;
    }
  }
}
```

The above uses [this constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) of `TextFormatter` which accepts a [`UnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html). This operator, known as the ["filter"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#getFilter()), can intercept changes to the text input control and either allow the change as is, alter it, or reject it altogether:

> The filter itself is an `UnaryOperator` that accepts [`TextFormatter.Change`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) object. It should return a [`TextFormatter.Change`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.Change.html) object that contains the actual (filtered) change. **Returning null rejects the change** [emphasis added].

Comment: Note that text may be deleted from places other than the end to the text. In such cases the result will be most likely invalid. That probably needs to be tested in the case of deletion...

Comment: Yes. After posting I realized there's some other cases I haven't taken care of, not just for deletion but also replacing text in the middle. I'm trying to fix these bugs currently.

Comment: One option is to simply test if `expectedText.startsWith(change.getControlNewText())` for every content change, which I had at first, but I feel that would get unnecessarily expensive if the expected text is long, especially as the actual text gets longer (though I haven't profiled this).

Comment: `expectedText.startsWith(change.getControlNewText().substring(firstModifiedPosition), firstModifiedPosition)`???

Comment: I decided to just not allow text replacements nor middle-of-text deletions. That seems acceptable considering the OP's stated purpose of their application.

Comment: interesting finger twitching at the start of a week near the end of the year :) Let me participate: given we start with an empty textArea and allow only additions such the the complete text is contained in the backing text to remember, then we only allow additions such that the complete text in the textArea is contained in the backing text (and disallow all additions that don't result in that state and all removes/replaces), in other words: the fragment in the area is always a valid part of the target text - or not? @fabian also (copied old comment for editing, keyboard had its own ideas ;)

Comment: @kleopatra The above (assuming no bugs) ensures that `expectedText.startsWith(area.getText())` is always true. Any change that would make that false is rejected. A side effect of this means you can only ever add text to, or remove text from, the end of the input. I decided to disallow replacements because either that would result in invalid input or it wouldn't, in which case the replacement had no practical effect anyway.

Comment: yeah I see, but why bother with inspecting the individual chars? Tending to (maybe over-) simplify, I would filter like `if (expectedText.contains(change.getControlNewText()) return change else return null`

Comment: @kleopatra Basically I'm checking that an appropriately ranged substring of the `expectedText` is equal to the just-added text (which typically will only be a single character at a time) without actually creating a new object via `String#substring`. Does avoiding that object allocation really help things? No idea, but I didn't find the above much harder to implement compared to using `substring`. I suppose `contains` may work in this context as well, but I have a vague hunch it could inappropriately return true sometimes since it doesn't take the positioning into account.

Comment: Actually, looking at the solution offered by @fabian again, which for whatever reason I misread and thus didn't fully understand at the time, it does basically the same thing I had but simpler (with regards to implementing/reading).

Comment: @kleopatra Still didn't use `contains`, but I believe the implementation is much simpler now.

Comment: startsWith looks good :) Personally, I wouldn't bother with a) restricting to range (except when noticing performance probs),  b) allowing deletions at all - but then, the question is suboptimal. Anyway, was cool to talk about :))

Comment: btw: my initial suggestion to use contains turned out to be no good - having some valid text "in the middle" requires to type backwards to enter the missing part before <g>